# What information does a Minecraft crash dump contain on its own?

Tags: discussion, minecraft, faq-proposed

A user just posted a Minecraft crash dump without context. What useful information should I be looking for if I wanted to even attempt to help them out?

Comment: Why is this on meta?

Comment: @badp Now that you mention it... I guess this could fit better on main, given some edits, obviously. I had sort of intended this originally to be a "don't just vote as unclear because you don't know their system details", but it kind of turned into a question about the game itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Minecraft crash dump contains a lot more information than people give them credit for. You have to dig for the information, sure, so providing something other than just a crash dump is very helpful, but you can often find out a lot of what you need to know from just the crash dump.

The section we're interested in is the "System Details" section. Let's ignore pretty much everything else for now; most of the time, all you need to know is here. This section contains the following bits of information:

- Minecraft Version
- Operating System
- Java Version
- How much memory Minecraft was allocated
- Versions of Forge, FML, and MCP (if applicable)
- Number of mods loaded
- Full list of mods

  - In the case of crash upon mod loading, which mods errored
- Graphics card and OpenGL version

You get the idea.

Keep in mind, though, there is a difference between a crash dump and a few lines from the console after it crashed. A crash dump often contains the information needed to fix what went wrong, a few lines from the console is rarely, if ever, enough information to know what's going on.

A crash dump doesn't tell us *everything* though: It usually isn't completely indicative of *when* the error occurred (on launch, on world load), and usually doesn't tell us if it's a problem that's specific to one world. It doesn't tell us what the user has tried to do to fix it.

So what's the point?

The point is, if a user has posted a crash dump, asking for a full list of mods is redundant. Asking what version they are using is, also, redundant. This information already exists in the question. It's not in the absolute most convenient format at the moment, sure, but the information is there. If you really want to gather new information, ask them when the error occurred (on game load or on world load), or ask them if they added one mod in particular that might be the cause of new crashes.

Conversely, if you're an asker, and someone asks you for a full mod list, this list can be found in your crash dump. So if you have only a handful of mods, it might be helpful to create a bulleted list of mods including version numbers. Formatting goes a long way when people judge technical issues questions.

Comment: Just want to add my two cents: You have made a strong point, but my argument sits with the ability for new users to read what is happening, and possibly avoid duplicate questions (I'm sure by now there are plenty of these, we just can't see them). While yes, we might be able to answer the question from nothing more than a crash dump, any other user won't be able to see the problem, and thus identify with it.

Comment: Don't forget about the stack trace!