# How do I ask Minecraft Questions?

Tags: discussion, minecraft, faq-proposed

*This Meta Question is the result from [This Meta Question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10088/vast-amounts-of-minecraft-crash-questions) ready to be used for the solution presented by [This Answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10094/30879) and made using the similar format to [This Anime/Manga Meta Question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793). (I am assuming that solution will be used, otherwise this still makes a great single stop reference for us to maintain)*

How do i ask a Minecraft Question as to avoid being downvoted/closed.

Comment: Isn't this what the [meta-tag:faq-proposed] tag is for?

Comment: @JonK I didn't realise that, strange I didn't see it when I first went to use the faq tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here on Arqade we expect a certain degree of research effort when it comes to asking questions as with any StackExchange Site. Below is a guide to hopeful help you in knowing what to look for, where to look, and how to ask question relating to Minecraft.

<sub>If your question is not about Minecraft crashing, see further below for information not pertaining to crashes.</sub>

---

## Minecraft Bugs/Crashes

When Minecraft Crashes the first thing you need to do is investigate as to why it crashed. If you ask a question like

> Minecraft has crashed while i was playing, HELP ME!

it won't be well received (downvoted and/or put on hold/closed). We need much more information than this. The following paragraphs provide an overview of how to get that information, either to help yourself, or for us to help you.

#### 1. Accessing and reading the crash dump

The first thing you should do is chase up your Minecraft Crash Dump. Hopefully you should be present with the following screen

[image: Minecraft crash report]

[What information does a Minecraft crash dump contain on its own?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10042/what-information-does-a-minecraft-crash-dump-contain-on-its-own/10043#10043)

As explained in the answer in the link above, this file can have a lot of useful information. While it can be overwhelming and a confusing read if you are not experienced, you can sometime diagnose the problem yourself by looking though here.

You can fine the crash dump at

- **Windows 7/XP/Vista:** `%appdata%/.minecraft`
- **Windows 8.x/10:** `Users/<Username>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft`
- **Linux:** `~/.minecraft/`
- **Mac:** `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`
  `Library` is normally hidden, you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to access it

The first thing you should do is compare the error you got to [this list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft). If you can find your error, do a [quick Google search](http://bit.ly/1CiLPvJ) in order to see if a solution has already been found.

Another thing you can do is to compare some information found in your crash dump to what you were expecting. For example:

- Does your Java/Minecraft/Forge/Whatever Version in the crash dump match to what you believe to be using?
- Do the listed mods match to the ones you've installed?

If they do not then investigating these issues first before asking a question, likewise using Google.

You should also check out the [Mojang's Support Page](https://help.mojang.com/) and [Mojang's Official Issue Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) if you are playing an unmodded version of Minecraft. It's possible that your bug is an existing problem or may have been fixed already.

#### 2. Check if your problem was asked before on Arqade

Still haven't fixed it? Now it's time to look here on Arqade! But once again, before you ask a new question, use Arqade's own search function in the top right corner of the page (Take care to use the one on the main (blue) site, not the one here on the META (grey) site). Google is not all-powerful, so this might just solve your problem. Some commonly asked and answered questions are:

- [Lost my bin folder and my minecraft binary files, what do I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120679/lost-my-bin-folder-and-my-minecraft-binary-files-what-do-i-do)
- [How to install mods for the new Minecraft launcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-launcher)

If your question still hasn't been answered then it's time to ask a new question.

#### 3. Asking the question

[How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question)

The above link is what we expect from any question. If you have a crash dump, some of the points in the link are already present (Mod List, Minecraft Version), but the more information you provide the better. Not all bugs/crashes have a crash dump (e.g. a player skin not loading correctly).

#### Things to look out for

- Installing Mods into versions of Minecraft much newer than what the mod recommends (e.g. a mod says it's for version 1.6 and you run it in 1.8)
- Running a Pre-Release version, these are in-development releases meant to help make the next proper release more stable, mods are normally not made to run with these versions and even Vanilla Minecraft can be prone to crashing.
- Be Patient. Arqade's users are all over the world and not everyone is on at the same time.

---

## Minecraft General Knowledge

Minecraft is a huge game and some people are more knowledgeable of the inner workings. Before asking a general knowledge Minecraft question review the [Minecraft Gamepedia Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_Wiki).

This will contain information on blocks, how Redstone Circuits work and what is different between [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft), [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) and [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition).

It also has a comprehensive list of what has been fixed in Development Releases and what has been added.

Of course we don't expect you to have memorized the entire wiki but sometimes, a quick wiki search will help you answer your question yourself.

Also remember to do a search for existing questions before asking a new one. Some commonly asked questions are:

- [How do command blocks work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132761/how-do-command-blocks-work)
- [What's the most efficient Minecraft mining strategy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy)
- [How to Join Games with Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/how-to-join-games-with-minecraft-pocket-edition-0-7)

If you are thinking of asking Recommendation Questions, Questions which would be primarily Opinion Based or Questions that are too localized ie.

- "What are some really great Minecraft servers?" (Recommendation Questions)
- "Which Map Mod is better? X or Y" (Primary Opinion Based)
- "What's a Seed I can use which will be near a village with this list of mods" (too localized, Primary Opinion Based)

Then it may be better to Ask in the [Minecraft Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk), of course, just like any other StackExchange Chat Room you'll need the [Privilege](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) to be able to post (you can view what's in the chat room regardless of rep)

#### Things to look out for

- [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) is generally used for PC Minecraft Questions. If you are running [minecraft-pocket-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-pocket-edition) or [minecraft-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-console) and use the wrong tag you may not end up getting an answer that will work for you.
- Be Patient. Arqade's users are all over the world and not everyone is on at the same time.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, and I will refer this many times to those who fail to provide enough information in their Minecarft questions to let us help them.